# Python: multiple function call appends to same list

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm coming from a Javascript background, and I know this works in Javascript, but what's fundamentally different here with Python?

I'm reading a CSV (sample below) and adding up all the values of a column (based on index parameter) into a list within the `get_min_max` function, sorting said list, and returning the first and last value in the list, for min and max, respectively.

The first call of `get_min_max` works great, but the second call fails. What happens is that the values from the second function call get appended to the first list.

How do I prevent the second function call from appending to the same list as the first function call? Clearly, I'm missing something fundamental about Python here.

### Sample CSV

```
0,11,23
1,34,67
2,86,99
3,45,21
4,60,98
5,2,123
6,7,12
7,9,0
```

### Sample Code

```
import csv

f = open("test.csv", "r")

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

def get_min_max(reader, index):
    arr=[]
    for row in reader:
        arr.append(row[index])
    arr.sort()
    return {
        "min": arr[0],
        "max": arr[-1]
    }

get_min_max(reader, 1) # call no. 1
get_min_max(reader, 2) # call no. 2
```

### ERROR

List index out of range on call no. 2. Returning the list on the second call returns empty list; returning the list on the first call returns list of values from the first call and the second call.

Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation can't be correct in your sample code. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second call, data from `reader` has been consumed and hence returns nothing.

This illustrates the problem:

```
>>> f = open("test.csv", "r")
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
>>> list(reader)
[['0', '11', '23'], ['1', '34', '67'], ['2', '86', '99'], ['3', '45', '21'], ['4', '60', '98'], ['5', '2', '123'], ['6', '7', '12'], ['7', '9', '0']]
>>> list(reader)
[]
```

Possible solutions: You can either cache the file data in some variables or reopen and read from the file within the function `get_min_max`

Comment: Oh good catch! I was looking for mutable default arguments and couldn't figure out why I wasn't finding any :D

Comment: @AdamSmith also you can implement a better function using min and max built python function. max([1,2,3]) returns 3, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors: one that Anthony mentioned (reader already consumed the file) and another one - you're sorting the numbers as "strings" which means that "11" < "2".

To fix it:

```
import csv

def get_min_max(filename, index):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    arr=[]
    for row in reader:
        arr.append(int(row[index])) # <-- second fix 
    arr.sort()
    return {
        "min": arr[0],
        "max": arr[-1]
    }

print get_min_max("test.csv", 1) # prints {'max': 86, 'min': 2}
print get_min_max("test.csv", 2) # prints {'max': 123, 'min': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you already read through the file. File objects are only itterable once. you have to seek back to the beginning of the file using `file.seek(0)` or cache the data. Also you should convert those strings to ints because it will cause weird things like 11<9.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers explain the cause of the program's failure.
If the file size is small(less than 10M), i suggest you first read file content into memeory then do whatever you what.

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    rows = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")]

def get_min_max(rows, index):
    arr=[]
    for row in rows:
        arr.append(row[index])
    arr.sort()
    return {
        "min": arr[0],
        "max": arr[-1]
    }

print get_min_max(rows, 1) # call no. 1
print get_min_max(rows, 2) # call no. 2
```

or use generator to decouple the file reader like this:

```
import csv

def csv_gen(fileName):
    with open(fileName, "r") as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=","):
            yield row

def get_min_max(rows, index):
    arr=[]
    for row in rows:
        arr.append(row[index])
    arr.sort()
    return {
        "min": arr[0],
        "max": arr[-1]
    }

print get_min_max(csv_gen("test.csv"), 1) # call no. 1
print get_min_max(csv_gen("test.csv"), 2) # call no. 2
```